# Can I able to use RP 1 and LOX in metal tin small size rockets? Is that possible?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, liquid-fuel, amateur-rocketry

I love rockets. Planning to build a tin rocket but not with water and air pressure. I would like to build a small metal tin rocket using fuel as RP 1 and oxidizer as LOX. I know this is too hazardous please don't try this. Is that possible to build a metal tin rocket with the same fuel used in real rockets?

Comment: A water bottle rocket by definition has no combustion. You are trying to pressurize your chamber with combustion, so this is not a question about bottle rockets but a liquid fueled rocket, even if you add water as reaction mass. Hence the close votes since you are trying to make a pipe bomb. As a place to start asking the right questions suggest Ignition! by J Clark and possibly the early history of the A4/V2.

Comment: Hi MuthukumaaranC and welcome to Space Exploration SE! This isn't a site for model rocket building, or even amateur rocket building of any kind. Have a look around at the other questions here to get an idea of what kinds of things are on-topic, or check out the section in the Help Center about [asking questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: LOX is some pretty nasty stuff.  This board isn't here to help you commit suicide.

Comment: After your edit to use a metal rocket body - https://rocketry.org.au/safety-information/model-rocket-safety-code/ rule one. To do otherwise at the hobby level is to be making pipe bombs and it is rule one for a very good reason. To get the question off hold you need to redefine it as 'how to I safely get into model rocketry', 'how does the space industry work with LOX' or similar

Comment: Even with editing, this question continues to be about dangerous experiments.  As such, it should remain closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- the heat of combustion would soon melt your plastic bottle. RP/LOX rockets use special high-temperature metals like Inconel, and then still need to cool the nozzle to prevent melting.
- a plastic bottle becomes brittle when you try to store LOX in it, it's unlikely to be strong enough to hold the LOX at any pressure

So we'd be talking about a different kind of rocket here: one built from metal, using two tanks to hold the LOX and RP, and with a combustion chamber to mix and ignite them.

The next step up from a bottle rocket is not LOX/RP. It's an [Estes](https://www.estesrockets.com/) solid-fuel rocket.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions

Comment: I disagree with the decision to declare all of model rocketry off-topic. That decision means we're sending people off into the wilderness instead of informing them.